# RedHat RHEL5.3 update DNS entry point of Windows 2003 domain on Debian style

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, redhat, dhcp, windows-server-2003-r2

I'm back today, because I can't do a trick that is simple to do on Debian.
Indeed, I'm using a RHEL 5.3 server as a DHCP client on Windows Domain.
To be able to correctly reach it form my windows clients, I'm trying to set it to be able to gently send it's hostname to the windows DHCP.

On my Debian bow, it's quite easy, I just have to edit my dhclient.conf file and add the two following options:

1°/- send host-name "server.domain.tld";

2°/- send fqdn.server-update on;

Now I try to do the trick on my RHEL, but unfortunatly there is no dhclient.conf file and I can't find anything about those two options or their equivalent on RHEL Network-script style.

So, if anyone can lead me on this problem, it will be greatly appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create the dhclient.conf file and let RHEL do its thing?

If not, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` should work if you add there

```
DHCP_HOSTNAME="yourhost.yourdomain"
```

value.

Comment: Indeed, RHEL dhclient is just named differently, I've finally found it after some googling.
DHCLIENT binary provided by RedHat is the same than for Debian, excepted that you have to look for a file named dhclient-ethx-config.conf and then add the precedent directives right on it ;-)

So, I guess that I can close this topic.
I've done what I was looking for, with your help and a little bit of more deeper search.

Once again, thanks a lot ServerFault's community ;-)